# Strange Error in Facebook opengraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am Trying to publish an action using js sdk.

my action code is

```
 function watchvid()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/video.watches?video=http://watchvideoz.in/watch.php?v=34',
        'post',
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {

              alert(JSON.stringify(response.error)); 
           } else {
var a = response.id;
    MyApp.color = a;

           }
        });
  }
```

and my meta tags are

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://watchvideoz.in/watch.php?v=34"/>    
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="288976161189701"/>  
<meta property="og:title" content="Buckys C++ Programming Tutorials - 9 - Functions"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bsWWHo4KDHE/hqdefault.jpg"/>   
<meta property="og:description" content="For all of our videos, visit http://thenewboston.com"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YourVidz"/>
```

But i get the Following error

```
{"message":"(#3502) Object at URL http://watchvideoz.in/watch.php?v has og:type of 'website'. The property 'video' requires an object of og:type 'video.other'. ","type":"OAuthException","code":3502}
```

In above error it ignores the value after **=**    i.e..it retrieves only **http://watchvideoz.in/watch.php?v**

Although the fb debugger tool is retrieving correct values

http://watchvideoz.in/watch.php?v=34

Comment: yea the debugger returns all correct values..it is strange for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a url as a querystring parameter you need to "url encode" it so that the '?' and '&' in your own querystring won't get confused with the one in the "parent" url.
Try http://watchvideoz.in/watch.phpp%3Fv%3D34